# Conflito de Namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Instalei o system.web.helpers e agora preciso instalar o system.web.mvc. Acontece que ambos possuem uma dependência chamada de: system.web.webpages e por isso a instalação do mvc está dando erro. Veja o erro abaixo:

```
Install-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 2.0.20505.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3' failed. Unable to find a version of 'microsoft-web-helpers' that is 
compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Como posso resolver esse conflito?

Comment: Olá, você está criando a aplicação a partir de uma Empty Solution ? Existe a posibilidade de você utilizar os templates que o VS disponibiliza ?

Comment: Então, deixa eu explicar. Não há dll nenhuma instalada. Aí tive que instalar o Helpers,para que pudesse estar disponível em qualquer projeto depois. Fiz isso e faltou instalar a MVC. Quando eu instalao pelo NuGet, dá esse pau. Dessa forma não tenho como adicionar uma referência ao meu projeto.

Comment: Como você fez a instalação do MVC ? Qual VS você está utilizando ? Caso seja o 2010 não é apenas pelo Nuget, você tem que entrar no site da Microsoft baixar e instalar segue link https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=30683.

Caso você esteja com um VS acima do 2010 vá em File/New/Project e selecione ASP.net Aplication e marque a opção de autenticação que você deseja . Segue link para tutorial https://cezarcruz.com.br/2013/09/criando-o-primeiro-projeto-aspnet-mvc-com-csharp/

Peço desculpas caso eu não esteja entendendo seu problema. Caso seja outra coisa favor me falar. OBG.